# New monitor - text looks bad both on and off applications, ClearType tuning won't apply

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display, hdmi, cleartype

I just received a new monitor from Acer, the XZ342CK, which is an 21:9 1440p 144hz monitor. I noticed a problem with viewing texts that was not present before changing to this new monitor (I was using a 16:9 1080p 144hz monitor). My graphics card is a GTX 970. The monitor is connected via DP port.

The infamous "red/blue" coloring on texts continue to appear. It seems like pretty much the only solution I get when googling the problem is going through ClearType text tuning built-in application, which I have tried many times - there definitely exist some text options with previews without these colored text issues, but when I complete the setup wizard by selecting these options, it simply does not apply the text setting that I've chosen.

Things I have tried:

- ClearType text tuning (from Control Panel item/by running cttune.exe)
- Turn on/off ClearType text
- Adjust text scaling
- Adjust display resolution to recommended/non-recommended
- Enable/disable accelerated 2D canvas on Chrome

I've also looked for a dedicated driver for the monitor but it seems like there isn't one. Can I get some insight from anyone? Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT: I've noticed that the problem is resolved when I use an HDMI cable instead of DP cable - but using HDMI cable caps the refresh rate at 100hz. Is this an unavoidable problem when using DP cable or will this be resolved if I purchase a new DP cable?

Comment: We can't know that. Try a new DP cable of good quality, and if this doesn't help then use the warranty to return the monitor.

Comment: @harrymc Yeah, I guess so. I've ordered a new DP cable from Amazon; hopefully, it fixes the issue!